# binding data to detailsview inside webpart and masterpage

Tags: master-pages, web-parts

i am having a master page with a webpartzone inside the webpartzone i am having a detailsview now i want to bind the data to the detailsview from one of the content form i tried but it is not working any ideas 
my code is
Dim myMaster As MasterPage = DirectCast(Me.Master, MasterPage)
         Dim webpt As WebPartZone = DirectCast(myMaster.FindControl("WebPartZone1"), WebPartZone)
        If Not IsNothing(webpt) Then
        Dim dv As DetailsView = CType(myMaster.FindControl("dvapqp"), DetailsView)
        dv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        dv.DataBind()
        End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i will answer my own question :-) i used a user control to display inside webparts and accessed it i explained it in my  [blog post](http://sansknowledge.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/accessing-controls-inside-a-web-part-zone/)